# Restore LDAP data from copied files

Tags: openldap, restore, gentoo, slapd

My server has broken and I had to urgently put it up again. I needed to reinstall the system and, since I was time constrained, I lazily just copied the directories I considered necessary (`/etc`, `/opt`, `/root` and `/var`) with `cp` to an external disk and formatted the system.

Now, I need to restore my LDAP configuration and data, but I did not do a backup correctly. I still have every single file because they were stored in `/var`, but copying them to the same place and starting `slapd` fails. I get the following messages on `/var/log/messages`:

```
Aug 25 21:02:33 localhost slapd[2664]: @(#) $OpenLDAP: slapd 2.4.38 (Aug 25 2014 16:04:17) $
    @host:/var/tmp/portage/net-nds/openldap-2.4.38-r2/work/openldap-2.4.38-abi_x86_64.amd64/servers/slapd
Aug 25 21:02:33 localhost slapd[2667]: hdb_db_open: database "dc=my,dc=host,dc=com": alock package is unstable.
Aug 25 21:02:33 localhost slapd[2667]: backend_startup_one (type=hdb, suffix="dc=my,dc=host,dc=com"): bi_db_open failed! (-1)
Aug 25 21:02:33 localhost slapd[2667]: slapd stopped.
Aug 25 21:02:33 localhost /etc/init.d/slapd[2663]: start-stop-daemon: failed to start `/usr/lib64/openldap/slapd'
Aug 25 21:02:33 localhost /etc/init.d/slapd[2647]: ERROR: slapd failed to start
```

I reinforce that I both have the old configuration files and a verbatin database files copy. If it is possible to recover with it, how should I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

I just completed my restore of openldap on ubuntu14.04 from files from ubuntu 12.04
restore your files for these two dirs.  be sure to backup the current contents before.

```
As root
1. backup contents of /var/lib/ldap/*
2. backup contents of /etc/ldap/*
3. sudo service slapd stop
4. clear out /var/lib/ldap/*
5. clear out /etc/ldap/*

6. cp [backup]/var/lib/ldap/* /var/lib/ldap/
7. cp [backup]/etc/ldap/* /etc/ldap/
8. chown openldap /etc/ldap/*
9. sudo service slapd start
```